# How to Optimize Slow Aggregation with Large Collection in MongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongodb-atlas

EDIT ----
Here how I managed to optimized but is not enough yet.
it seems that the $setWindowFields stage is causing the slowdown

```
[
      {
        "$limit": 1
      },
      {
        "$lookup": {
          "from": "mobile_devices",
          "pipeline": [
            {
              "$match": {
                "orgUnitPath": {
                  "$regularExpression": {
                    "pattern": "^/",
                    "options": "i"
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "$setWindowFields": {
                "output": {
                  "totalCount": {
                    "$count": {}
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "$limit": 100
            },
            {
              "$project": {
                "_id": 0
              }
            }
          ],
          "as": "mobiledevices"
        }
      },
      {
        "$addFields": {
          "nextPageToken": {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                "$lt": [
                  100,
                  "$mobiledevices.totalCount"
                ]
              },
              "then": "MTAw",
              "else": "$$REMOVE"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "$unset": "mobiledevices.totalCount"
      },
      {
        "$group": {
          "_id": "_id",
          "kind": {
            "$first": "$kind"
          },
          "etag": {
            "$first": "$etag"
          },
          "mobiledevices": {
            "$first": "$mobiledevices"
          },
          "nextPageToken": {
            "$first": "$nextPageToken"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "$project": {
          "_id": 0
        }
      },
      {
        "$set": {
          "nextPageToken": {
            "$ifNull": [
              "$nextPageToken",
              "$$REMOVE"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

I have an aggregation pipeline in MongoDB that processes a collection (collection_list) of several gigabytes. The current aggregation is taking too much time to complete. The pipeline returns results in the following format:

```json
{
  "nextPageToken": "MTA=",
  "kind": "admin#directory#mobiledevices",
  "etag": "\sdsd",
  "target_model": [
    {
      // ...
    },
    // ...
  ]
}
```

Upon investigating the performance, it seems that the `$unwind` stage is causing the slowdown. Here is the current aggregation pipeline:

```python
lookup_pipeline = []
if scopes_ou_path:
    """Concatenate all OU paths with a regex OR operator,
    e.g.: ["/vesa", "/europe/france"] -> "^/vesa|^/europe/france"""
    scopes_ou_path = "^" + "|^".join(scopes_ou_path)
    lookup_pipeline.append(
        {"$match": {"orgUnitPath": {"$regex": scopes_ou_path, "$options": "i"}}}
    )
skip, next_page = manage_next_page_token(next_page_token=next_page, limit=limit)
if filters:
    lookup_pipeline.append({"$match": filters})  # type: ignore
if skip:
    lookup_pipeline.append({"$skip": skip})  # type: ignore
lookup_pipeline.append(
    {"$setWindowFields": {"output": {"totalCount": {"$count": {}}}}}  # type: ignore
)
if limit:
    lookup_pipeline.append({"$limit": limit})  # type: ignore
lookup_pipeline.append({"$project": {"_id": 0}})  # type: ignore
return [
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": collection_list,
            "pipeline": lookup_pipeline,
            "as": target_model,
        },
    },
    {"$unwind": {"path": f"${target_model}"}},
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "nextPageToken": {
                "$cond": {
                    "if": {
                        "$lt": [limit, f"${target_model}.totalCount"],
                    },
                    "then": next_page,
                    "else": "$$REMOVE",
                },
            },
        },
    },
    {
        "$unset": f"{target_model}.totalCount",
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "_id",
            "kind": {"$first": "$kind"},
            "etag": {"$first": "$etag"},
            f"{target_model}": {"$push": f"${target_model}"},
            "nextPageToken": {"$first": "$nextPageToken"},
        },
    },
    {"$project": {"_id": 0}},
    {
        "$set": {
            "nextPageToken": {
                "$ifNull": ["$nextPageToken", "$$REMOVE"],
            },
        },
    },
]
```

I've noticed that `$unwind` takes considerable time. Is there a way to optimize this aggregation pipeline and improve its performance without using `$unwind`? Any guidance or alternative approaches to speed up the aggregation would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `"$unwind"`/`"$group"` stage pairs can often be replaced with `"$reduce"` and/or `"$map"`.  You may want to explore doing that.

Comment: reduce will be faster dans unwind?

Comment: Usually.  You can always implement several pipelines are profile them on your data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Final Optimization. Went to 88sec to 7 sec
The main issue was {"$setWindowFields": {"output": {"totalCount": {"$count": {}}}}}.
Replaced by $facet

```
[
      {
        "$limit": 1
      },
      {
        "$lookup": {
          "from": "mobile_devices",
          "pipeline": [
            {
              "$match": {
                "orgUnitPath": {
                  "$regularExpression": {
                    "pattern": "^/",
                    "options": "i"
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "$facet": {
                "total": [
                  {
                    "$count": "totalCount"
                  }
                ],
                "data": [
                  {
                    "$limit": 100
                  },
                  {
                    "$project": {
                      "_id": 0
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ],
          "as": "mobiledevices"
        }
      },
      {
        "$unwind": {
          "path": "$mobiledevices"
        }
      },
      {
        "$addFields": {
          "nextPageToken": {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                "$lt": [
                  100,
                  {
                    "$first": "$mobiledevices.total.totalCount"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "then": "MTAw",
              "else": "$$REMOVE"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "$group": {
          "_id": "_id",
          "kind": {
            "$first": "$kind"
          },
          "etag": {
            "$first": "$etag"
          },
          "mobiledevices": {
            "$first": "$mobiledevices.data"
          },
          "nextPageToken": {
            "$first": "$nextPageToken"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "$project": {
          "_id": 0
        }
      },
      {
        "$set": {
          "nextPageToken": {
            "$ifNull": [
              "$nextPageToken",
              "$$REMOVE"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```